# PHP MYSQL - Image upload error

Tags: php, database, upload, mysqli, image

I'm totally new using databases, so maybe my problem is something obvious. My variables are in danish, I hope you'll understand anyway. I have already searched in the forum, but because this is new to me, I find it very hard to understand.

A user should create a profile with a profile picture, but an error happens when I try to save it. My own defined error pops up because `$billednavn == false`.

The code:

```
<?php  

// 1. Gem modtagne formulardata i variabler:  
$navn = $_POST['navn'];  
$alder = $_POST['alder'];  
$postnr = $_POST['postnr'];  
$mail = $_POST['mail'];  
$billede = $_FILES['profilbillede'];  
$password = $_POST['password'];  



// 2. Forbind til databasen:  
$databaselink = mysqli_connect("localhost","mmddk3e12m8b18", "****", "mmddk3e12m8b18") or die     ("Fejl: Kan ikke etablere forbindelse til database");



$billednavn = billedupload($billede);  
// besked til brugeren om at der er sket en fejl    
if($billednavn == false){  
die("Der skete en fejl under upload af billedet");
}



// 3. Udform insert SQL streng med de modtagne data, og udfør SQL strengen på databasen vha     mysqli_query:  
$query = "INSERT INTO brugere (navn, alder, postnr, mail, password, profilbillede) VALUES ('$navn', '$alder', '$postnr', '$mail', '$password', '$billednavn')";  
$result = mysqli_query($databaselink, $query) or die( "Forespørgslen kunne ikke udføres: " .         mysqli_error($databaselink));  

// 4. luk databasen:  
mysqli_close($databaselink);  

function billedupload($fil){  
if($fil['type']=='image/jpeg' or $fil['type']=='image/png'){  
$tmp_navn = $fil['tmp_name'];  
$filnavn = $fil['name'];  
$target = 'images/' . time() . $filnavn;  
move_uploaded_file($tmp_navn,$target);  
return $target;  
}  
else{  
return false;  
}  
}  

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$_FILES` is set? Debug it with `var_dump($_FILES)`. If not, you may miss a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`

Comment: @Blauesocke Sorry , just saw you posted it after I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

If it returns false, then - by your definition, either the file type isn't image/jpeg or it isn't image/png, or the type isn't set, or the entire $_FILES isn't set.

In your HTML form make sure you have `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">` and try `var_dump($_FILES);` in your PHP file to validate your POST data.

**EDIT:**
In the condition where tmp_name is empty there are two possible situations i can think of:

1. You forgot to set `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` (more likely, please validate that)
2. In your php.ini make sure `file_uploads` are set to `On`

The first option is more probable, Of course.

Comment: The file type was png. and the enctype was already set.  
How do I use var_dump? I don't know that command  
  
Now I get this error:  
  

_Warning: move_uploaded_file(web/images/1357640382portrætmig.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mmddk3e12m8b18/public_html/web/oprettet.php on line 38  
  
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/var/tmp/phpPcUSlZ' to 'web/images/1357640382portrætmig.jpg' in /home/mmddk3e12m8b18/public_html/web/oprettet.php on line 38_

Comment: I found out how to use it. It says: array(1) { ["profilbillede"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Gordon.jpg" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Update my answer per your added info. Please paste your HTML code and PHP code in pastebin.com or similar if you require additional assistance.